# Tengo un problema con MYSQL y LINUX al alterar un valor

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este codigo para actualizar un item por ejemplo si la cantidad esta en 8 y le sumo 2, al actualizar la pagina el cambio se guarda pero no se porque sale el error. **alert('Algo salió mal. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo');**

antes tenia el servicio en windows y funcionama bien al pasarlo a linux salio el error

esto hago para en el update

```
public function update_item_qty($type, $id, $fromqty, $qty) {
    $to = $fromqty + $qty;

    if(!is_numeric($id) || !is_numeric($fromqty) || !is_numeric($qty))
        die('inc/items_core.php - update_item_qty - Non Numeric Values');

    // Primero actualiza el item
    if($type == 1) {
        $prepared = $this->prepare("UPDATE invento_items SET qty = qty+$qty WHERE id=?", 'update_item_qty()');
        $this->bind_param($prepared->bind_param('i', $id), 'update_item_qty()');
        $this->execute($prepared, 'update_item_qty()');
    }elseif($type == 2){
        $prepared = $this->prepare("UPDATE invento_items SET qty = qty-$qty WHERE id=?", 'update_item_qty()');
        $this->bind_param($prepared->bind_param('i', $id), 'update_item_qty()');
        $this->execute($prepared, 'update_item_qty()');
    }
```

PHP

```
// Actualiza la cantidad de items (Salidas/Entradas)
if($_POST['act'] == '3' || $_POST['act'] == '4') {
    if(!isset($_POST['id']) || !isset($_POST['val']) || !isset($_POST['fromval']) || $_POST['id'] == '' || $_POST['val'] == '' || $_POST['fromval'] == '')
        die('wrong');
    if($_POST['act'] == '3')
        $type = 1;
    elseif($_POST['act'] == '4') {
        $type = 2;
        $qty = $_items->get_item($_POST['id']);
        $qty = $qty->qty;
        if($qty < $_POST['val'])
            die('2');
    }

    if($_items->update_item_qty($type, $_POST['id'], $_POST['fromval'], $_POST['val']) == true)
        die('1');
    die('wrong');
```

JS

```
$.post('items.php', {
        'act':act,
        'id':id,
        'fromval':prev_value,
        'val':val
    }, function(data) {
        if(data == '2') {
            alert('No puedes ver más de '+prev_value+' referencias');
            return false;
        }else if(data == '1'){
            t.parent().parent().fadeOut(300, function() { this.remove(); });
            t.parent().parent().prev().children('td:nth-child(5)').fadeOut(200, function() {
                if(act == 3)
                    t.parent().parent().prev().children('td:nth-child(5)').html(parseInt(prev_value)+parseInt(val)).fadeIn(400);
                else if(act == 4)
                    t.parent().parent().prev().children('td:nth-child(5)').html(parseInt(prev_value)-parseInt(val)).fadeIn(400);
            });
        }else{
            alert('10 Algo salió mal. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo');
        }
    });
```

Comment: El mensaje que dices no aparece en el código que compartes. Es difícil poder ayudarte así.

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te aparece?

Comment: ¿Que te regresa data? ¿Te esta regresando 1?

Comment: No e poddido configurar el debuger en VSCODE pada php

Comment: En el php te falta la llave de cierre o no pusiste todo el codigo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione cambiando el alert donde dice

> alert('10 Algo salió mal. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo');

por

> location.reload();

```
$.post('items.php', {
        'act':act,
        'id':id,
        'fromval':prev_value,
        'val':val
    }, function(data) {
        if(data == '2') {
            alert('No puedes ver más de '+prev_value+' referencias');
            return false;
        }else if(data == '1'){
            t.parent().parent().fadeOut(300, function() { this.remove(); });
            t.parent().parent().prev().children('td:nth-child(5)').fadeOut(200, function() {
                if(act == 3)
                    t.parent().parent().prev().children('td:nth-child(5)').html(parseInt(prev_value)+parseInt(val)).fadeIn(400);
                else if(act == 4)
                    t.parent().parent().prev().children('td:nth-child(5)').html(parseInt(prev_value)-parseInt(val)).fadeIn(400);
            });
        }else{
            alert('10 Algo salió mal. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo');
        }
    });
```